# Does it make sense to use the word Dynasty in place of clan in a multiplayer game similar to clash of clans?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

We are developing a multiplayer game.
Is it OK to use "Dynasty" for the group of players?
I don't want the two words to have the same meaning. 
But I want it to make sense to use the word "Dynasty" for a group of people with a manager where people can join and leave the group. 
Is it OK?

Comment: You can call your group by any name you want, but that doesn't make it universally mean the thing you want it to mean.

Comment: Generally speaking, you don't *join or leave* a dynasty. You simply belong or don't by virtue of birthright. If you're talking about arbitrary groups with changing membership, then I would simply look up [synonyms for clan](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/clan) and see which of those sound better. (Such as *league* or *faction*. . .)

Comment: I agree with @JasonBassford If membership is transitory, dynasty doesn't feel like a good fit.  Consider instead: guild, club, crew, gang. squad.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about the English language.

Comment: @Xanne What's it about then? This question is about the usage (proper usage) of an English word...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Central to the meaning of [Dynasty](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dynasty) is a bloodline: power or influence inherited through a family, maintained over generations. If your application's gameplay or lore reflect that, it would be a good name. But for voluntary associations with appointed, elected or *ad hoc* managers, it would be inaccurate.